# How to determine the path for Gmail credentials file?

Tags: python, email, flask, automation, gmail

Hello I am trying to pass in the correct path for my Gmail E-Mail sending automation credentials.json file on a Windows Machine. I have a working directory that uses Flask/React. The problem is now that I cannot find the correct path to open my credentials.json which is in the same folder as my program. When I use a Visual Studio Project I can just pass in "credentials.json" as argument.

When I try to pass in the normal path I receive an error message that states "Cannot decode bytes". I cannot use r" in front of the path because then google uses doubleslashes and I receive an error message which prints that the file cannot be found. I cannot switch the slashes because then the file cannot be found either. Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you!

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import base64

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']




def send_email(Message):
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):

        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            #############Here is the problem with the file path######################################
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\BusinessApplication\react_flask\PlotlyFlask\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
       service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)


       message = MIMEText(text)
       message['to'] = 'me@example.com'
       message['subject'] = 'Email Subject'
       create_message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}
       message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
       print(F'sent message to {message} Message Id: {message["id"]}')

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

text="test"

send_email(text)
```

Comment: _Does anyone have a solution?_ Yes -- use the actual correct filepath.  If python says the file doesn't exist, then I believe it.  You're using the wrong filepath.

Comment: Hi it says: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: That error is because you're using single backslashes and you didn't put `r` in front of the string.  Either use forward slashes (yes, they work, even on Windows), or put the `r` in front, or (as a last resort) use doubled backslashes.

Comment: putting r in front: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\BusinessApplication\\react_flask\\PlotlyFlask\\credentials.json'

Comment: one single forward backslash: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/BusinessApplication/react_flask/PlotlyFlask/credentials.json'

Comment: Double Backslashes: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\BusinessApplication\\react_flask\\PlotlyFlask\\credentials.json'

Comment: Okay, so as I said in my first comment, **you're using the wrong filepath**.  That file really, truly, does not exist.

Comment: You can see the files that **actually do** exist in that directory with this bit of code: `import os; print(os.listdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BusinessApplication/react_flask/PlotlyFlask'))`

Comment: Also, I assume `/User/` would be your actual username, which you have changed here for privacy reasons.  Does your real string have the correct username?

Comment: This is my actual name.

Comment: if its in the current directory with the file have you tried credentials.json

Comment: I put the ending .json at the end of the filename

Comment: So the real filename was `credentials.json.json` ?

Comment: That was the filename.

Comment: That's kind of what I suspected.  When you originally saved that file, the save dialog box automatically saved it as a json file, so it put a `.json` file extension on the end.  But you typed in a filename that **also** had `.json` in it, so it got used twice.